# Stop UIButtons interfering with UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiscrollview, uibutton

I've got a UIScrollView. It's a narrow horizontal strip with a number of buttons. I want the user to be able to scroll the view, as well as tap the buttons.

```
------------------------
|                      |
| button 1    button2  |  (and button 3,4 etc) outside the frame
|                      |
------------------------
```

However, during user testing an issue has arisen. The user will put their finger on the area where a button is, and then attempt to scroll. Because they held their finger momentarily down on the button, the touch never goes thru to the scroll view.

How would I let the touches go down to the scroll view if the user starts to slide left or right with their finger? But still allow taps on the buttons?

Comment: What is the setting of the `delaysContentTouches` property of your `UIScrollView`?

Comment: It is YES. NO doesn't let me scroll at all, since the button take up all the space on the scroll view.

Answer (score 1):

You can mimic the buttons and add tapgesture recognisers on them. I think that way you can scroll over the buttons and also swipe depending on the action generated by the gesture recognisers.

Let me know if you need more info.

Edit:

Create a UIImage view and add the button images to them. Now Add tapgesture recognizers on them. Now the gesture callback will be invoked on touch only. The swipe/pan will work as usual on the scroll view.

Comment: Yes, please let me know more.